# stanford NER breaks a phrase into two for NER

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford NER on text and find out it breaks my phrase into two. Is it possible to control the granularity of the splitting of words?

For example, the text

```
text = "This is Tomma Waston who answer what US looks like."
```

returns:

```
[('This', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('Tomma', 'PERSON'), ('Waston', 'PERSON'), 
('who', 'O'), ('answer', 'O'), ('what', 'O'), ('US', 'LOCATION'), ('looks', 'O'), 
('like', 'O'), ('.', 'O')]
```

However, I know Tomma Waston is a single entity that shouldn't be split! How to solve this issue? Is it a common issue in NER and how to solve it?